# Why the electric shock from the lotion bottle?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

Just went to use a family-size bottle of Gold Bond Intensive Healing Lotion with my daughter for the first time and it took about 4-5 pumps to prime the lotion. When the lotion finally came out a spark of electricity that could be heard and seen jumped from the lotion to our skin. This happened for the first 4+/- uses and then it stopped. Any idea why this would happen? Haven’t been able to find an answer as to why but plenty of similar experiences being reported out there. TIA!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics

Answer (score 0):

Yes & No. Why the shock from the “lotion” actually. The spark and shock jumped from the lotion to the skin, not from the bottle.